# Do uSD card needs ESD protection?

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, sd, esd

I am working with bunch of uSD card. The place where i work is not ESD protected so i am just concerned if these devices can get damaged by the discharged current.
Can someone help ?

Comment: Check the manual/packing/marketing material, if available, for the devices. They may mention ESD protection/rating there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SD and micro-SD cards are designed to be handled by end users; as such, they should be at least reasonably resistant to ESD damage. I wouldn't go around zapping them on purpose, but you shouldn't need any special protection to work with them.

Answer (score 3):

SD cards may carry static voltages, but are not damaged by them; Flash memory devices are made to be resilient to the potential spikes they encounter on a daily basis. Otherwise, they would never have caught on in cameras and phones.

The charges cards carry may pose a threat to the *devices* they interface with; [TI discusses voltage clamping and EMI filters](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sszb130b/sszb130b.pdf) for device interfaces. [EMI filters are preferred for SD card interfaces](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/esd-protection-tvs-filtering-and-signal-conditioning/application-specific-esd-and-esd-emi-solutions/memory-and-sim-card-protection-and-filtering:MC_56905?cof=0&am=0) due to their small size.

Of course, you may be in a more professional setting with less common risks, but as long as you are not running Tesla coils or opening up the cards, no extra ESD precautions seem necessary. If the information on the cards is remotely valuable, back it up, because no practical amount of ESD will protect against the sorts of accidents that *are* likely.

Comment: Those TI products are intended to protect the product **into which you insert the SD card**, like the camera, PC etc. Since the SD card and/or the human holding the SD card could be ESD charged, ESD protection is needed in that product. The TI document is not stating anything about the ESD protection on the SD card itself.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked the emphasis on SD card **interfaces**. Corrected.